# Drupal Webform is sending emails but there are no values

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

The email that my webform is sending only has this... no actual values as entered into the form?

Submitted values are:
[submission:values]

Please help!

Comment: Do you wants the individual fields value?

Comment: Which version of webform you are using?

Comment: Webform 7.x-4.14

Answer (score 1):

In the Webform configuration under advanced settings to configure the general Webform settings go to `admin/config/content/webform`

- Advanced settings : Check off `Allow tokens to be used in Webforms`

Comment: Ok great. You can accept your answer so it will removed from unanswered questions queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `%value[key]` once and check.

Example:

First Name:  `%value[first_name]`

Last Name:   `%value[last_name]`

---

OR

```
First Name: [submission:values:first_name]
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but that didn't fix it.  I added the values you put above (replacing my field name key) and the result is still just the exact characters in the template rather than the entries in the fields.

Comment: Should the webform work on localhost?  Thought I would test there to see if I can figure out if this is an issue with Drupal or an issue with my server.

Comment: yes, but you need to configure for email sending on localhost.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what fixed it.  But it's fixed on one site.  I've compared that site with the other one having the same issue and can't get it working.   I noticed on the site that is working, there is an "available tokens" link which allows you to lookup fields to pass into your email.  On the site that isn't working, that link is missing.  Also, for the webform subject, it's trying to pull [node:title] - on the configuration screen of the site that works, it replaces this with my webform title name.  On the site that doesn't, it shows [node:title].